# Typesetting a variable which has both accent and subscript

Tags: math-mode, symbols

How to typeset a variable like:

[image: A with hat and 0 as index]

Whether do I write `$\hat{A}\vphantom{A}_0$` or simply write `$\hat{A}_0$`? (I had seen the former in a template).

BTW, what about `$f'^2$`? Is `$f^{\prime2}$` or `$f^{\prime\,2}$` or `${f^{\prime}}^2$` or `$f^{\prime}\vphantom{f}^2$`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just `$\hat{A}_0$` is OK. `\vphantom` is even harmful, for some letter like `I`.

Comment: @L.L. What about `$f'^2$`? Is `$f^{\prime2}$` or `$f^{\prime\,2}$` or `${f^{\prime}}^2$` or `$f^{\prime}\vphantom{f}^2$`?

Comment: I think `(f')^2` is better.